# Why compareing two date is not working properly in java.util.date?

Tags: java, spring, date

I have three date:

1. Delivery Time(string)
2. StartDate(long)
3. EndDate(long)

if delivery date is taken place between startdate and enddate,then addition will be done. But the date can not be compared properly and also date format is not working properly.

Here is my code:

```
private long addTotalLiveBirthChild(Members member) {

        String deliveryDateStr = member.details().get("DOO");
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dooDate = null;
        Date startDate = new Date(startDateTime);
        Date endDate = new Date(endDateTime);
        try {
            dooDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(deliveryDateStr);
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(startDate);
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(endDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println("DeliveryDate:" + dooDate + " startDate:" + startDate + " endDate:" + endDate);
        if(dooDate.after(startDate)   && dooDate.before(endDate) ){

            totalCountOfLiveBirth = totalCountOfLiveBirth + Long.parseLong(member.details().get("Num_Live_Birth"));
        }
        return totalCountOfLiveBirth;
    }
```

Here is the print result:

[image: Here is the print result:]

Comment: from what I see, all delivery date's are before startDate, what do  you expect to get?

Comment: I just want to compare date,not time.

Comment: @OUNAsh Did you try my answer?

Comment: `I just want to compare date,not time` <--- what does that even mean? don't u wanna see if deliveryDate is between startDate and endDate? if so, what I see from printout, is develiryDate is NOT between startDate and endDate...

Comment: What are the values of `startDateTime`, `endDateTime` and `deliveryDateStr`?

Comment: @Nafas- you are right!!!! there is  problem in date- thank you so much. I have solved it

Answer (score 0):

```
private long addTotalLiveBirthChild(Members member) {

        String deliveryDateStr = member.details().get("DOO");
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dooDate = null;
        Date startDate = new Date(startDateTime);
        Date endDate = new Date(endDateTime);
        try {
            dooDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(deliveryDateStr);
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(startDate); // return String representation, which you don't use anywhere
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(endDate); // return String representation, which you don't use anywhere
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println("DeliveryDate:" + dooDate + " startDate:" + startDate + " endDate:" + endDate);
        if(dooDate.after(startDate)   && dooDate.before(endDate) ){

            totalCountOfLiveBirth = totalCountOfLiveBirth + Long.parseLong(member.details().get("Num_Live_Birth"));
        }
        return totalCountOfLiveBirth;
    }
```

See my comments above (return String representation, which you don't use anywhere). You don't need this lines.

As I understand you want to compare only dates, without time. Then you should use this function:

```
public static Date zeroTimeDate(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

    return calendar.getTime();
}

Date startDate = zeroTimeDate(new Date(startDateTime));
Date endDate = zeroTimeDate(new Date(endDateTime));
```

Note:
If you could use Java 8 Date API it could be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it simple.

Step:

1. Don´t compare Strings, it´s logical to compare numbers!
2. Convert the Deliverytime into an long
3. simple if() to determ weather it´s in the date or not
4. Stop thinking that you have to understand the code, ofc. we are humans and can "see" if it is between or out of the dates we compare. But a machine needs numbers to perform best.

Like this:

```
  long deliverytime,starttime,endtime;
//.. declare values and convert them from string to long
  if(deliverytime > starttime && deliverytime < endtime){
      //do your stuff
  } else {
      //it´s not between
  }
```

I encounter this problem more in sql, that people safe data that they can understand, but they wonder why a DB has truble with true/false but not with 0/1.

***Important***
Dateformat is used to display a date for the user, you as programmer shouldn´t work with it in the code, except as textview.settext(formatdate);